# Функция mt_rand на денвере

Tags: php

В мануале php четко написано:

> Она использует генератор случайных
> чисел с известными характеристиками,
> основанный на "Вихре Мерсенна",
> который генерирует случайные числа в
> среднем в четыре раза быстрее, чем
> libc rand().

```
$time = microtime(true);
for($i=0;$i<10000000;$i++){
    mt_rand(0,1000000);
}
print(microtime(true)-$time);

print('<br />');

$time = microtime(true);
for($i=0;$i<10000000;$i++){
    rand(0,1000000);
}
print(microtime(true)-$time);
```

Выдает

```
13.71744799614
13.259204864502
```

Что я делаю не так?!

Comment: видимо просто тестируете скорость цикла.

Comment: Неа, пустой цикл дает так:

    1.8112969398499
    1.8054568767548

Comment: Похоже, Вы не единственный, который делает подобные тесты и удивляется, потому что ожидает как минимум 4 кратного прироста. Я смотрел детально, похоже эти две функции используют различные функции (rand использует php->random(), а вот mt_rand похоже использует openssl функции или "шифруется").

Но ускорения похоже ни у кого нет. Интересное пишут [здесь](http://golearnphp.com/php-rand-vs-mt_rand-and-openssl_random_pseudo_bytes/).

Comment: Подозреваю, что с тех пор, как документацию писали, libc неоднократо обновилась.

Comment: >потому что ожидает как минимум 4 кратного прироста

Я имею права ожидать, как минимум не ухудшения! =) 4 раза - ладно, но 1,5-то можно?!

>libc неоднократо обновилась.

Ну, доки там тоже довольно свежие, обычно.

Comment: @knes, входные\выходные данные с php4 не менялись - зачем переписывать документацию?

Comment: @KoVadim, в статье по ссылке написали, что rand()===mt_rand(), если стоит экстенжн. Но тогда просто вообще не понятно, почему mt медленнее.

Comment: то, что у Вас получилось, это не медленее, это в пределах погрешности. Я запускал тест несколько раз и результаты были разные. Но плюс-минус пару процентов.